# How can I have multiple caches of the same page with different query arguments?

Tags: 8, caching

Using Drupal 8, I have a page (a node) that has two different renderings depending on a passed in query parameter. This is to support a regular page view in a browser and also an embedded version of the page without the header, footer, etc. Example:

https://www.domain.com/my-page
https://www.domain.com/my-page?version=embedded_view

I've implemented this by using THEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter() in my .theme file to suggest a different page template to use depending on the query parameter. (Perhaps there's a better way.)

When viewed on a site with caching enabled, both of the URLs return the same rendering of the page. How do I get different cached versions for the two URLs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add a cache context for the query parameter `version` to the page:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args:version';

}
```

The context will then be used to vary the cached pages by this query argument.

Comment: Thank you! And noted on the correct D8 tagging of posts.

Comment: @4k4 can you help me ? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233565/use-external-class-in-drupal-8-module-with-file-name-and-class-name